# Как узнать установлен ли composer и если так, то как его запустить?

Tags: composer

Работаю с удалённым сервером, через подлючение по ssh. В папке с файлами сайта есть файлы **composer.json** и **composer.lock** и я так полагаю, что это значит, что композер установлен на сервере. Команды git и php через консоль выполняются без каких либо проблем, но когда я пишу composer, выводится `-bash: composer: command not found` Сам я с ним толком не знаком, а как мне сказали, мне нужно установить его пакеты через команду `composer update --no-dev` может я что-то не так делаю? А если всё так, то как его можно запустить?

Comment: В общем, скачал композер через команду `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` дал права `chmod +x composer.phar` дальше пишу `php composer.phar update --no-dev` и вылезает ошибка

Comment: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1` дальше много-много `- symfony/var-dumper v4.4.9 requires php >=7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- symfony/var-dumper v4.4.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- symfony/var-dumper v4.4.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.` вот такого текста

Comment: и потом `Running update with --no-dev does not mean require-dev is ignored, it just means the packages will not be installed. If dev requirements are blocking the update you have to resolve those problems.`

Comment: кто-нибудь может подсказать решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, единственное, что помогло - это повышение версии php до 7.2